# HTML2pdf/tcpdf using php not working properly

Tags: php, tcpdf, html2pdf

I want to get content from html and want to create pdf file based on it.
I have tried *html2pdf* as well *tcpdf*.But somehow in both places i didn't get working as i expected.

I am working on invoice template which can be modified from web.But right now issue i am facing like showing in GUI with proper output but when i am trying to use html2pdf showing me different output than GUI.

Is there anyway to achieve it ?

Code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/css/keditor-1.1.4.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/css/keditor-components-1.1.4.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/examples.css" />
<script src="plugins/jquery-1.11.3/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../examples/plugins/bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jquery.nicescroll-3.6.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/ckeditor-4.5.6/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/ckeditor-4.5.6/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/keditor-1.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/keditor-components-1.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="keditor-content-area-1500637983301" class="keditor-content-area ui-droppable ui-sortable">
        <section class="keditor-container keditor-initialized-container" id="keditor-container-1500637983322"><section class="keditor-container-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 keditor-container-content ui-droppable ui-sortable" data-type="container-content" id="keditor-container-content-1500637983324">
                    <section data-type="component-text" class="keditor-component existing-component keditor-initialized-component" id="keditor-component-1500637983336"><section class="keditor-component-content cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" id="keditor-component-content-1500637983337" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="false" aria-describedby="cke_49" contenteditable="true"><div class="page-header"><h1 style="margin-bottom: 30px; font-size: 50px;"><b class="text-uppercase">Welcome to KEditor</b> <small>Kademi Editor</small></h1><p class="lead"><em>It's open source editor based-on CKEditor with support drag and drop snippets. This example is using <a data-cke-saved-href="http://getbootstrap.com/" href="http://getbootstrap.com/" target="_blank">Bootstrap 3.3.6</a> for styling</em></p></div></section><div class="keditor-toolbar keditor-toolbar-component">   <a href="#" class="btn-component-reposition"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></a>   <a href="#" class="btn-component-duplicate"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></a>   <a href="#" class="btn-component-delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div></section>
                    <section data-type="component-text" class="keditor-component existing-component keditor-initialized-component" id="keditor-component-1500637983350"><section class="keditor-component-content cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" id="keditor-component-content-1500637983350" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="false" aria-describedby="cke_87" contenteditable="true"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 text-center"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" data-cke-saved-src="snippets/default/img/somewhere_bangladesh_squared.jpg" src="snippets/default/img/somewhere_bangladesh_squared.jpg"><h3>Lorem ipsum</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel, alias, temporibus? Vero natus modi ipsa debitis, accusamus accusantium cum quam. Saepe atque quisquam pariatur voluptatem expedita nesciunt reprehenderit et vitae.</p></div><div class="col-md-4 text-center"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" data-cke-saved-src="snippets/default/img/wellington_newzealand_squared.jpg" src="snippets/default/img/wellington_newzealand_squared.jpg"><h3>Lorem ipsum</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, aut, earum. Quod, debitis, delectus. Maxime eius ipsam sit dolorum perspiciatis obcaecati consectetur, explicabo reprehenderit repellat tempore veniam eos ducimus! Dignissimos.</p></div><div class="col-md-4 text-center"><img class="img-circle img-responsive" data-cke-saved-src="snippets/default/img/yenbai_vietnam_squared.jpg" src="snippets/default/img/yenbai_vietnam_squared.jpg"><h3>Lorem ipsum</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil voluptatibus dicta corrupti aliquam, natus voluptatem pariatur quidem nostrum nisi corporis id ratione exercitationem et recusandae incidunt assumenda soluta qui odit.</p></div></div></section><div class="keditor-toolbar keditor-toolbar-component">   <a href="#" class="btn-component-reposition"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></a>   <a href="#" class="btn-component-duplicate"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></a>   <a href="#" class="btn-component-delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div></section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><div class="keditor-toolbar keditor-toolbar-container">   <a href="#" class="btn-container-reposition"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></a>   <a href="#" class="btn-container-duplicate"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></a>   <a href="#" class="btn-container-delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div></section>
    </div>
```

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrwAE.png)

But  when i am trying html2pdf or tcpdf both are not showing  content as i can see in web page.

It is showing one image and then its content and then another image and its content.

Comment: There are certain limitations of these APIs in terms of rendering your HTML and CSS in a PDF file. So you should not expect the exact thing to appear in the PDF file as it is visible in your web page. Some of the CSS attributes and styling does not work like in a web page. While some styling effects only work when applied inline.